# Convex set in a vector space gives a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Given an $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ vector space $X$ and a function
$p:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ with $p(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ and $p(\alpha x)=|\alpha|p(x)$ for all $x,\alpha$, I want to show that $p$ is a norm iff $\{x|p(x)\le1\}$ is convex.

I can show the $\Rightarrow$-direction but am stuck with the other one. I know that I have to show $p(x+y)\le p(x)+p(y)$ but don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$ you're done, since $p(y)\le p(y)$. Similarly if $y=0$. So assume $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$.

Let $C=\{x:p(x)\le 1\}$. Assume $C$ is convex. Now $$\frac x{p(x)},\frac y{p(y)}\in C.$$ Let $$t=\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)}\in[0,1].$$Then
$$C\ni t\frac{x}{p(x)}+(1-t)\frac{y}{p(y)}=\frac{x+y}{p(x)+p(y)}.$$So $$p\left(\frac{x+y}{p(x)+p(y)}\right)\le1,$$hence $p(x+y)\le p(x)+p(y)$.