# How we got $\frac{x+y}{p(x)+p(y)}?$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given an $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ vector space $X$ and a function
$p:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ with $p(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ and $p(\alpha x)=|\alpha|p(x)$ for all $x,\alpha$.  show that $p$ is a norm iff $\{x|p(x)\le1\}$ is convex.

My attempt :  i found the  answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1804621/557708

But i have  some  doubts  in the given  answer   , my doubt  have been marks in  round red circle
[image]

My confusion $$t\frac{x}{p(x)}+(1-t)\frac{y}{p(y)}=\frac{x+y}{p(x)+p(y)}.$$

How  we got $\frac{x+y}{p(x)+p(y)}?$

My thinking  $$t\frac{x}{p(x)}+(1-t)\frac{y}{p(y)}=\frac{txp(y)+ p(x)y - ytp(x)}{p(x)p(y)} $$

Comment: Just substitute $t=\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because\begin{align}\require{cancel}t\frac x{p(x)}+(1-t)\frac y{p(y)}&=\frac{txp(y)+(1-t)yp(x)}{p(x)p(y)}\\&=\frac{\frac{x\cancel{p(x)p(y)}}{p(x)+p(y)}+\frac{y\cancel{p(y)p(x)}}{p(x)+p(y)}}{\cancel{p(x)p(y)}}\\&=\frac{x+y}{p(x)+p(y)}.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You just need to plug $t=\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)}$ into the formula and simplify:
$$t\frac{x}{p(x)}=\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)}\cdot \frac{x}{p(x)}=\frac{x}{p(x)+p(y)}$$
and 
$$(1-t)\frac{y}{p(y)}=\left(1-\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)}\right)\frac{y}{p(y)}=\frac{p(y)}{p(x)+p(y)}\cdot \frac{y}{p(y)}=\frac{y}{p(x)+p(y)}$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition of $t$ we get $t \frac x {p(x)}+(1-t)\frac  y {p(y)}= \frac x {p(x)+p(y)} +\frac y {p(x)+p(y)}$